# How to set arrow icon center to the screen end in list item in react native

Tags: react-native, view

I am new to react native, In my application I have list. So that i have taken flatlist. I have designed the list item. But arrow icon need to set end of the item. I have tried many ways how to do this.

This is the my code

```
<View style={styles.MainContainer}>

      <FlatList

          data={ this.state.FlatListItems }

          ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}

          renderItem={
            ({item}) => 
             <View style={styles.main}>
               <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
                 <View>
                   <Image source={require('./resource/ic_drawer.png')}  />
                   <Text style={styles.item} onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.key)} >
                      {item.key} 
                   </Text> 
                 </View>

                 <View style={styles.balanceItem}>
                   <View>
                     <Text >Balance</Text>
                     <Text >$89.04</Text>
                   </View>

                   <View style={styles.subItem}>
                     <View>
                       <Text >Account number</Text>
                       <Text >743509-001</Text>
                     </View>
                     <View style={styles.balanceItem}>
                       <Text >Meter number</Text>
                       <Text >17976849</Text>
                     </View>
                   </View>
                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.balanceItem}>
                    <View style={styles.duenbuttonItem}>
                       <View>
                         <Text >Due Date</Text>
                         <Text >30/09/2016</Text>
                       </View>
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={this.login}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>PAY NOW</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>



                </View>   
                <Image source={require('./resource/arrow_24.png')} style={styles.arrowImage}/>   
               </View>   
          }
      />


  </View>
```

and this is my styles

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  MainContainer :{

  // Setting up View inside content in Vertically center.
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex:1,
    margin: 10

  },

  item: {
    padding: 0,
    fontSize: 18,
  },

  itemContainer :{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding : 10,
  },

  subItem: {
    marginTop: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },

  btn:{
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#003366',
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',  
  },
  balanceItem: {
    marginLeft: 5,
  },
  duenbuttonItem: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  arrowImage: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  main:{
    flex: 1,
  }

});
```

And this the output of the above code

[image]

Here my requirement is the arrow image end of the item in center. So please guide me how to do this?

Comment: set alignSelf:center in arrowImage's style

Comment: Thank you for your response. by using this it will get center of the bottom of item

Comment: any way it will be useful